# Implements through inheritance

Tags: vb.net

I'm having issues implementing an interface which vb.net is not picking it up through inheritance, not sure its possible but i believe there should be a way

```
Public Interface ITest

    Sub SomeMethod()

End Interface

Public Class Test
    Inherits OtherClass
    Implements ITest

End Class

Public Class OtherClass

    Sub SomeMethod()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Class "OtherClass" is on another assembly where that ITest interface does not live and I cant have it there. However, with c# you are not forced to use the Implements keyword on each method, c# looks through the name and signatures.

So basically, Im getting the "Missing implementation of members" and what I was expecting was to be able to compile fine since Im inheriting a class that has the same methods defined on the interface.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why would `OtherClass` have `SomeMethod`?  It does not implement the ITest interface and does not inherit from anything that does.

Comment: im trying to create an assembly that "shadows" an underlying api that will be replaced in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `OtherClass` to implement the `ITest` interface, it **needs** a reference to that `ITest` interface.

Once you have it referenced, then your OtherClass would look like this:

```
Public Class OtherClass
  Implements ITest

  Sub SomeMethod() Implements ITest.SomeMethod

  End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: thats the thing, i dont want / cant, add that interface to the otherclass assembly. its probably not possible

Comment: @user1533223 Then what's the point?  You have a class called OtherClass that has a method call SomeMethod.  What isn't working?